# How do I set the accuracy of the displayed values?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, 3d-view, interface

Good afternoon.

There is another problem.

I have a wall with a height of 2.6 m and a width of 5.04 m.

In edit mode, when the Face Info -> Area checkbox is selected (in the Mesh Display list), the area of 13.1 square meters is displayed.

But!
2.6 * 5.04 = 13.104 square meters.

Question - how and where can I set the accuracy of the displayed values?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Hello :). I've seen this discussed on many sites going years back, and it seems this behavior cannot currently be changed. It might work with some addon though. Good luck, and let us know if you solve it.